# PHP Error Video Not Play With Expiring/Signed video embed urls

Tags: php

Hello Everyone I'm Using This Code In My Project But When I'm Trying This Code I got Url Like This
 `http://localhost/getVideo.php?s=kowBvl8VcTfPnStNTCpOfekAeCEgyVfDyEjK8j1JPn4%2FanwbUVvnXHVqbXRyz13gvMCDALvCFzJ7NSSLLikcraQv9%2F4qXgGahfppv8wbyjU%3D`

But After Getting This URL When I'm Trying This URL For Play I Got The Message 
`This URL has expired.` and Already Set Expiring Time In Seconds `libraries/VideoSignature.php` Expiring Time 86400 24hrs but Video not played

Used Code:

[How to make Expiring/Signed video embed urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068432/how-to-make-expiring-signed-video-embed-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved

`<video src="<?=$vs->getSignedURL("http://localhost/sfdf.mp4");?>"></video>`
Just Remove `http://localhost/`

Now URL Working fine

Thanks Everyone